# Test app lifecycle, destruction and creation

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I need to test my apps lifecycle and its destruction and re-creation, because when the keyboard slides in/out (or is rotated), the app is destroyed and re-created. I also need to test for memory leaks when it does this.

I saw in the tutorial http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html#StateManagementTests

```
Terminate the activity and restart it:
mActivity.finish();
mActivity = this.getActivity();
```

However this is very simplified. My logging seems to indicate that calling finish() spawns a background thread with a different thread id which then calls onPause(), finish(), onStop(), and onDestroy(). I even tried `getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();` to try to wait for that background thread to complete, but I still get race conditions when I test for expected values.

Not only that, but when it re-creates the Activity (when the 1st race condition doesn't occur or I comment out the assert), with getActivity(), then it just returns the exact same object that I just finished! I can tell because I log `this` in my onXXX...() methods.

This differs from the orientation rotation / keyboard sliding app lifecycle, which always creates a new Activity object.

So how can I test this destruction / reincarnation scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it! It involves LOTs of waitForIdleSync() since it is multi-threaded to begin with, and setActivity(null). I could only get within +- 30% of the same memory. I would like to give credit to Peter Carpenter too, because his idea sped up my app and I would never have thought of that!

```
public void testMemoryLeaks() {
    Log.e(TAG, "------------ testMemoryLeaks()");
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    System.gc();
    Main mActivity = getActivity();
    Log.d(TAG, "-- Extractor.stop() "+mActivity.getExtractor());
    mActivity.getExtractor().stop();
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    System.gc();
    long mem = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    Log.d(TAG, "-- freeMemory: " + mem);
    Log.d(TAG, "-- mActivity.finish()");
    mActivity.finish();
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    Log.d(TAG, "-- setActivity()");
    setActivity(null);
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    System.gc();
    Log.d(TAG, "-- getActivity()");
    mActivity = getActivity();
    assertTrue(mActivity != null);
    Log.d(TAG, "-- Extractor.stop() "+mActivity.getExtractor());
    mActivity.getExtractor().stop();
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    System.gc();
    long memAfter = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    Log.d(TAG, "-- freeMemory: " + memAfter);
    assertTrue("Memory leak", mem > memAfter * .70 && mem < memAfter * 1.30);
    mActivity.finish();
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    Log.d(TAG, "-- end testMemoryLeaks()");
}
```

Comment: any idea, on what condition, 'getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();' would get into infinite loop? In android 4.4.2_r2 running processor board, I'm facing this issue, while executing the CTS Test.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to replicate the orientation change is to actually do it. (Keypad #7 key)  Perhaps what you're really after is to prevent the app from being killed on orientation change.... ;)  You can do this by overriding the onConfigurationChanged() function in your activity.  see:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: What do you mean keypad #7 key? When I try to type anything, including `7`, it goes to search. I think `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` is a great idea to speed it up! However, I'd still like to test the lifecycle with a unit test to ensure it doesn't leak memory when the app is killed in the background.

Comment: If you're using the emulator, the number 7 key on your computers keypad will change the orientation of the emulator for you.  If you're trying to do this automatically in a unit test, you could try myActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);